# Joined attributes not recognized in mean coordinates

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I am trying to find mean coordinates of a shapefile to which I have joined a CSV file for population attributes, but these will not show.

I'm working with county data of each US state based on the year 1860. I have the shapefile for the states which has polygons as counties. It has its own set of attributes but not that of population in the year 1860.

I imported the CSV file and joined the data to the original shapefile of the state. This all works fine.

The problem comes when I try to use the mean coordinate function to make a weighted centroid it does not recognize the joined attributes.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Attributes which I have joined to the shapefile to use for finding mean coordinate]

[image: Columns not showing up in mean coordinates weight field]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mean coordinates tool in the Vector menu does not seem to support joined fields but you can use the newer version of the tool which is located in the **Processing toolbox**: in this example ELEV is from the original attribute table and airports_ELEV is from the joined attribute table

[image]